# Debugging tools for the R language

Tags: debugging, r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [General suggestions for debugging R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442518/general-suggestions-for-debugging-r)

After learning R about 9 months ago, I am finally graduating from debugging by using `print()` statements every other line.  I am now a pretty constant user of `browser()` and `debug()`.  I have recently become aware of a few more tools: `traceback()`, `trace()`, and `recover()`.

Does anybody have advice on when (and how) to use these?