# General suggestions for debugging in R

Tags: r, debugging, r-faq

I get an error when using an R function that I wrote:

```
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
```

**What I have done:**

1. Step through the function
2. Adding print to find out at what line the error occurs suggests two functions that should not use `glm.fit`.  They are `window()` and `save()`.

My general approaches include adding `print` and `stop` commands, and stepping through a function line by line until I can locate the exception.

However, it is not clear to me using those techniques where this error comes from in the code. I am not even certain which functions within the code depend on `glm.fit`.  How do I go about diagnosing this problem?

Comment: Check out Duncan Murdoch's page on [Debugging in R](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/murdoch/software/debuggingR/)

Comment: The `edit()` and `fix()` functions can also be quite helpful.

Comment: I also use the function "mtrace" (and then mtrace.off()) on a function (from the "debug" package), which is amazingly useful.

Comment: Ok, I'll state the obvious: that is a **warning** not an **error**.

Comment: @gavin-simpson I did not realize that there was a technical difference, thanks for pointing that out. But in the end, it indicates that my previously functional function is dysfunctional.

Comment: @David +1 for "...my previously functional function is dysfunctional."

Comment: @David; may be not. `glm.fit` uses an iterative algorithm with a convergence criterion. For some of your fits, the algorithm did not reach convergence for some reason; possibly because it reached the maximum number of iterations allowed (25 default). You will need to investigate why it didn't converge, and I've shown some examples of how to force R to enter debugger mode when that warning arises.

Comment: @David: re your p.s.. This adds a dimension to the question that would have been missed without the example; namely how to get R to step into debugging mode when only warnings are produced? If you had left this detail out, we'd all not have pointed you to `options(warn = 2)`. So in this case, the detail is essential to answering your general question. +1 from me.

Comment: I haven't used it myself (yet), but [ESS-tracebug](http://code.google.com/p/ess-tracebug/) looks like a very nice interactive debugger if you use ESS.

Comment: StatET 2.00+ now has experimental support for advanced/visual debugging. It requires Eclipse 3.6 or 3.7 Installation instructions are here: http://www.walware.de/?page=/it/downloads/statet.mframe You can see a snippet of video from UseR! 2011 here: http://vimeo.com/27901400

Answer (score 171, accepted):

I'd say that debugging is an art form, so there's no clear silver bullet.  There are good strategies for debugging in any language, and they apply here too (e.g. [read this nice article](http://web.archive.org/web/20070607153252/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-debug.html)).  For instance, the first thing is to *reproduce the problem*...if you can't do that, then you need to get more information (e.g. with logging).  Once you can reproduce it, you need to *reduce* it down to the source.

Rather than a "trick", I would say that I have a favorite debugging routine:

1. When an error occurs, the first thing that I usually do is look at the stack trace by calling `traceback()`: that shows you where the error occurred, which is especially useful if you have  several nested functions.
2. Next I will set `options(error=recover)`; this immediately switches into browser mode where the error occurs, so you can browse the workspace from there.
3. If I still don't have enough information, I usually use the `debug()` function and step through the script line by line.

The best new trick in R 2.10 (when working with script files) is to use the `findLineNum()` and `setBreakpoint()` functions.

As a final comment: depending upon the error, it is also very helpful to set `try()` or `tryCatch()` statements around external function calls (especially when dealing with S4 classes).  That will sometimes provide even more information, and it also gives you more control over how errors are handled at run time.

These related questions have a lot of suggestions:

- [Debugging tools for the R language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169480/debugging-tools-for-the-r-language)
- [Debugging lapply/sapply calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395622/debugging-lapply-sapply-calls)
- [Getting the state of variables after an error occurs in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412582/getting-the-state-of-variables-after-an-error-occurs-in-r)
- [R script line numbers at error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445964/r-script-line-numbers-at-error)

Comment: You could add debugonce() to debug() as well.

Comment: Although not only useful when debugging, fix(df1) opens the graphical R Editor with data frame df1 loaded in it which you can edit on the fly or just take a glance at.

Comment: debugging in R seems to be very hard, for example [there is no easy solution to see code lines of warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15190022/684229)

Comment: ``browser()`` for when there are errors that don't trigger warnings/errors (credit: Roman Luštrik on this page). Any other tool like ``browser()``?

Answer (score 40):

The best walkthrough I've seen so far is:

http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/%7Erpeng/docs/R-debug-tools.pdf

Anybody agree/disagree?

Comment: Very thorough guide- describes essential tools included in R core: debug(),traceback() and recover().

Answer (score 34):

As was pointed out to me in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156035/what-debugging-tools-does-r-lack-that-other-languages-have), `Rprof()` and `summaryRprof()` are nice tools to [find slow parts of your program](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/useR2009hpcTutorial.pdf) that might benefit from speeding up or moving to a C/C++ implementation.  This probably applies more if you're doing simulation work or other compute- or data-intensive activities.  The [`profr` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/profr/profr.pdf) can help visualizing the results.

I'm on a bit of a learn-about-debugging kick, so another suggestion from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442518/general-suggestions-for-debugging-r):

- Set `options(warn=2)` to treat warnings like errors

You can also use `options` to drop you right into the heat of the action when an error or warning occurs, using your favorite debugging function of choice.  For instance:

- Set `options(error=recover)` to run `recover()` when an error occurs, as Shane noted (and as is documented in the [R debugging guide](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/docs/R-debug-tools.pdf).  Or any other handy function you would find useful to have run.

And another two methods from one of @Shane's [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395622/debugging-lapply-sapply-calls):

- Wrap an inner function call with `try()` to return more information on it.
- For *apply functions, use `.inform=TRUE` (from the plyr package) as an option to the apply command

@JoshuaUlrich [also pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142339/r-continue-executing-after-browser) a neat way of using the conditional abilities of the classic `browser()` command to turn on/off debugging:

- Put inside the function you might want to debug `browser(expr=isTRUE(getOption("myDebug")))`
- And set the global option by `options(myDebug=TRUE)`
- You could even wrap the browser call: `myBrowse <- browser(expr=isTRUE(getOption("myDebug")))` and then call with `myBrowse()` since it uses globals.

Then there are the new functions available in R 2.10:

- `findLineNum()` takes a source file name and line number and returns the function and environment.  This seems to be helpful when you `source()` a .R file and it returns an error at line #n, but you need to know what function is located at line #n.
- `setBreakpoint()` takes a source file name and line number and sets a breakpoint there

The [codetools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/codetools/codetools.pdf) package, and particularly its `checkUsage` function can be particularly helpful in quickly picking up syntax and stylistic errors that a compiler would typically report (unused locals, undefined global functions and variables, partial argument matching, and so forth).

`setBreakpoint()` is a more user-friendly front-end to `trace()`.  Details on the internals of how this works are available in a [recent R Journal article](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Murdoch.pdf).

If you are trying to debug someone else's package, once you have located the problem you can [over-write their functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674716/forcing-a-packages-function-to-use-user-provided-function) with `fixInNamespace` and `assignInNamespace`, but do not use this in production code.

None of this should preclude the tried-and-true [standard R debugging tools](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/murdoch/software/debuggingR/), some of which are above and others of which are not.  In particular, the [post-mortem debugging tools](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/murdoch/software/debuggingR/pmd.shtml) are handy when you have a time-consuming bunch of code that you'd rather not re-run.

Finally, for tricky problems which don't seem to throw an error message, you can use `options(error=dump.frames)` as detailed in this question:
[Error without an error being thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507442/error-without-an-error-being-thrown)

Comment: +1 for all the work you've put into merging these questions into one and then keeping it open!

Answer (score 31):

At some point, `glm.fit` is being called. That means one of the functions you call or one of the functions called by those functions is using either `glm`, `glm.fit`.

Also, as I mention in my comment above, that is a **warning** not an **error**, which makes a big difference. You can't trigger any of R's debugging tools from a warning (with default options before someone tells me I am wrong ;-).

If we change the options to turn warnings into errors then we can start to use R's debugging tools. From `?options` we have:

```
 ‘warn’: sets the handling of warning messages.  If ‘warn’ is
      negative all warnings are ignored.  If ‘warn’ is zero (the
      default) warnings are stored until the top-level function
      returns.  If fewer than 10 warnings were signalled they will
      be printed otherwise a message saying how many (max 50) were
      signalled.  An object called ‘last.warning’ is created and
      can be printed through the function ‘warnings’.  If ‘warn’ is
      one, warnings are printed as they occur.  If ‘warn’ is two or
      larger all warnings are turned into errors.
```

So if you run

```
options(warn = 2)
```

then run your code, R will throw an error. At which point, you could run

```
traceback()
```

to see the call stack. Here is an example.

```
> options(warn = 2)
> foo <- function(x) bar(x + 2)
> bar <- function(y) warning("don't want to use 'y'!")
> foo(1)
Error in bar(x + 2) : (converted from warning) don't want to use 'y'!
> traceback()
7: doWithOneRestart(return(expr), restart)
6: withOneRestart(expr, restarts[[1L]])
5: withRestarts({
       .Internal(.signalCondition(simpleWarning(msg, call), msg, 
           call))
       .Internal(.dfltWarn(msg, call))
   }, muffleWarning = function() NULL)
4: .signalSimpleWarning("don't want to use 'y'!", quote(bar(x + 
       2)))
3: warning("don't want to use 'y'!")
2: bar(x + 2)
1: foo(1)
```

Here you can ignore the frames marked `4:` and higher. We see that `foo` called `bar` and that `bar` generated the warning. That should show you which functions were calling `glm.fit`.

If you now want to debug this, we can turn to another option to tell R to enter the debugger when it encounters an error, and as we have made warnings errors we will get a debugger when the original warning is triggered. For that you should run:

```
options(error = recover)
```

Here is an example:

```
> options(error = recover)
> foo(1)
Error in bar(x + 2) : (converted from warning) don't want to use 'y'!

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: foo(1)
2: bar(x + 2)
3: warning("don't want to use 'y'!")
4: .signalSimpleWarning("don't want to use 'y'!", quote(bar(x + 2)))
5: withRestarts({
6: withOneRestart(expr, restarts[[1]])
7: doWithOneRestart(return(expr), restart)

Selection:
```

You can then step into any of those frames to see what was happening when the warning was thrown.

To reset the above options to their default, enter

```
options(error = NULL, warn = 0)
```

As for the specific warning you quote, it is highly likely that you need to allow more iterations in the code. Once you've found out what is calling `glm.fit`, work out how to pass it the `control` argument using `glm.control` - see `?glm.control`.

Comment: great answer. one note of pessimism is that these sorts of convergence errors often occur with unstable/wonky data sets (complete separation, etc.), and the window between 'converges just fine' and 'non-convergent but can't be fixed by increasing number of iterations -- needs some more drastic change' is often narrow

Comment: Gavin, I beat you by 25 seconds.  I demand you remove your overly-helpful answer and stop stealing my upvotes. ;-)

Comment: @Ben great point. If David's issue is separation then increasing the number of iterations shouldn't help, it should still fail to converge. At that point looking at the estimates and standard errors might suggest there is a problem. I would also expect to see the warning about fitted values numerically 0 or 1 if separation or similar were a problem. If upping the number of iterations doesn't help, David can post another Q for help and I can steal more of @Joshua's upvotes ;-)

Comment: @Joshua, there's no way to beat him. I stopped counting the upvotes i might have lost because of him. But anyway the help he provide accounts for that by far. Gotta find your own niches were you beat him. I suggest upvotes per keystroke here... :)

Comment: Dammit @ran2, you've foiled my dastardly, devious plan to take over the *world*, Mwahahahahaha!!!!

Answer (score 24):

So `browser()`, `traceback()` and `debug()` walk into a bar, but `trace()` waits outside and keeps the motor running.

By inserting `browser` somewhere in your function, the execution will halt and wait for your input. You can move forward using <kbd>n</kbd> (or <kbd>Enter</kbd>), run the entire chunk (iteration) with <kbd>c</kbd>, finish the current loop/function with <kbd>f</kbd>, or quit with <kbd>Q</kbd>; see `?browser`.

With `debug`, you get the same effect as with browser, but this stops the execution of a function at its beginning. Same shortcuts apply. This function will be in a "debug" mode until you turn it off using `undebug` (that is, after `debug(foo)`, running the function `foo` will enter "debug" mode every time until you run `undebug(foo)`).

A more transient alternative is `debugonce`, which will remove the "debug" mode from the function after the next time it's evaluated.

`traceback` will give you the flow of execution of functions all the way up to where something went wrong (an actual error).

You can insert code bits (i.e. custom functions) in functions using `trace`, for example `browser`. This is useful for functions from packages and you're too lazy to get the nicely folded source code.

Answer (score 19):

My general strategy looks like:

1. Run `traceback()` to see look for obvious issues
2. Set `options(warn=2)` to treat warnings like errors
3. Set `options(error=recover)` to step into the call stack on error

Answer (score 16):

After going through all the steps suggested here I just learned that setting `.verbose = TRUE` in `foreach()` also gives me tons of useful information.  In particular `foreach(.verbose=TRUE)` shows exactly where an error occurs inside the foreach loop, while `traceback()` does not look inside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 14):

Mark Bravington's debugger which is available as the package `debug` on CRAN is very good and pretty straight forward.

```
library(debug);
mtrace(myfunction);
myfunction(a,b);
#... debugging, can query objects, step, skip, run, breakpoints etc..
qqq(); # quit the debugger only
mtrace.off(); # turn off debugging
```

The code pops up in a highlighted Tk window so you can see what's going on and, of course you can call another `mtrace()` while in a different function.

HTH

Answer (score 12):

I like Gavin's answer: I did not know about options(error = recover). I also like to use the 'debug' package that gives a visual way to step through your code.

```
require(debug)
mtrace(foo)
foo(1)
```

At this point it opens up a separate debug window showing your function, with a yellow line showing where you are in the code. In the main window the code enters debug mode, and you can keep hitting enter to step through the code (and there are other commands as well), and examine variable values, etc. The yellow line in the debug window keeps moving to show where you are in the code. When done with debugging, you can turn off tracing with:

```
mtrace.off()
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on the answer I received [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8943443/168775), you should definitely check out the [`options(error=recover)`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/options.html) setting. When this is set, upon encountering an error, you'll see text on the console similar to the following (`traceback` output):

```
> source(<my filename>)
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: source(<my filename>)
2: eval.with.vis(ei, envir)
3: eval.with.vis(expr, envir, enclos)
4: LinearParamSearch(data = dataset, y = data.frame(LGD = dataset$LGD10), data.names = data
5: LinearParamSearch.R#66: plot(x = x, y = y.data, xlab = names(y), ylab = data.names[i])
6: LinearParamSearch.R#66: plot.default(x = x, y = y.data, xlab = names(y), ylab = data.nam
7: LinearParamSearch.R#66: localWindow(xlim, ylim, log, asp, ...)
8: LinearParamSearch.R#66: plot.window(...)

Selection:
```

At which point you can choose which "frame" to enter. When you make a selection, you'll be placed into `browser()` mode:

```
Selection: 4
Called from: stop(gettextf("replacement has %d rows, data has %d", N, n), 
    domain = NA)
Browse[1]>
```

And you can examine the environment as it was at the time of the error. When you're done, type `c` to bring you back to the frame selection menu. When you're done, as it tells you, type `0` to exit.

Answer (score 5):

I gave this answer to a [more recent question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588435/r-debugging-code) but am adding it here for completeness.

Personally I tend not to use functions to debug. I often find that this causes as much trouble as it solves. Also, coming from a Matlab background I like being able to do this in an integrated development environment (IDE) rather than doing this in the code. Using an IDE keeps your code clean and simple.

For R, I use an IDE called "RStudio" (http://www.rstudio.com), which is available for windows, mac, and linux and is pretty easy to use.

Versions of Rstudio since about October 2013 (0.98ish?) have the capability to add breakpoints in scripts and functions: to do this, just click on the left margin of the file to add a breakpoint. You can set a breakpoint and then step through from that point on. You also have access to all of the data in that environment, so you can try out commands.

See http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/debugging/overview for details.  If you already have Rstudio installed, you may need to upgrade - this is a relatively new (late 2013) feature.

You may also find other IDEs that have similar functionality.

Admittedly, if it's a built-in function you may have to resort to some of the suggestions made by other people in this discussion. But, if it's your own code that needs fixing, an IDE-based solution might be just what you need.

Answer (score 1):

To debug **Reference Class** methods without instance reference

```
ClassName$trace(methodName, browser)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am beginning to think that not printing error line number - a most basic requirement -  BY DEFAILT-  is some kind of a joke in **R/Rstudio**. The only reliable method I have found to find where an error occurred is to make the additional effort of calloing **traceback()** and see the top line.