# Can you make R print more detailed error messages?

Tags: r, error-handling

I've often been frustrated by R's cryptic error messages. I'm not talking about during an interactive session, I mean when you're running a script. Error messages don't print out line numbers, and it's often hard to trace the offending line, and the reason for the error (even if you can find the location).

Most recently my R script failed with the the incredibly insightful message: "Execution halted." The way I usually trace such errors is by putting a lot of print statements throughout the script -- but this is a pain. I sometimes have to go through the script line by line in an interactive session to find the error.

Does anyone have a better solution for how to make R error output more informative?

EDIT: Many R-debugging things work for interactive sessions. I'm looking for help on command-line scripts run through Rscript. I'm not in the middle of an R session when the error happens, I'm at the bash shell. I can't run "traceback()"

Comment: Look into dump.frames. Allows you to interactively debug a batch script after it has failed.

Comment: has there been any movement on this one? I'm having the same struggle and it's unbearable..

Comment: I don't believe there exists a satisfying answer to this problem yet.

Answer (score 9):

Try some of the suggestions in this post:

[General suggestions for debugging in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4442518/635160)

Specifically, `findLineNum()` and `traceback()`/`setBreakpoint()`.

Comment: Most of these suggestions pertain to loading interactive R and running scripts with source(). What about using Rscript on the command-line? I went through all these suggestions but can't figure out how to print out line numbers. It only works when using source()

Comment: @sheffien For interactive use, either `options(error=recover)` or `debugonce` can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

@Nathan Well add this line `sink(stdout(), type="message")` at the beginning of the script and you should get in console message both script content and output along with error message so you can see it as in interactive mode in the console. (you can then also redirect to a log file if you prefer keeping the console "clean")

Comment: This actually doesn't change anything for me

Comment: does this change something that should be changed back?  Is it like "par"?

Answer (score 0):

One way inside a script to get more info on where the error occurred is to redirect R message to the same stream as errors :

```
sink(stdout(), type="message")
```

This way you get both messages and errors in the same output so you see which line raised the error...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at *my* package `tryCatchLog` (https://github.com/aryoda/tryCatchLog).

While it is impossible to improve the R error messages directly you can save a lot of time by identifying the exact code line of the error and have actual variables at the moment of the error stored in a dump for "post mortem" analysis!

The main advantages of the `tryCatchLog` function over `tryCatch` are

- **easy logging** of errors, warnings and messages into a file or console
- warnings do not stop the program execution (tryCatch stops the execution if you pass a warning handler function)
- identifies the source of errors and warnings by logging a **stack trace with a reference to the source file name and line number** (since traceback does not contain the full stack trace)
- allows **post-mortem analysis after errors by creating a dump file** with all variables of the global environment (workspace) and each function called (via dump.frames) - very helpful for batch jobs that you cannot debug on the server directly to reproduce the error!

Answer (score 0):

This will show a more detailed traceback, but not the line number:

```
options(error = function() {traceback(2, max.lines=100); if(!interactive()) quit(save="no", status=1, runLast=T)})
```