# R: failure to allocate memory, how to determine how much memory was requested

Tags: r, memory, system

I am working with a package that has an algorithm that at some point, if you give it too many inputs, runs out of memory and gives this warning:

```
warning message system call failed cannot allocate memory
```

Is there a way to determine how much memory was requested that could not be allocated? I'm trying to determine whether I should/can scale up to a bigger box.

Thanks.

Comment: see `pryr::object_size`

Comment: @AlexW since the allocation that fails is buried deep in a package, I'd rather not have to modify that package. Also if the memory is not allocated, won't there not be an object for which to get the size?

Comment: Your question is **"how do I determine how much memory was requested to be allocated"**. I answered that question. If you have a different question, please revise your post and provide a reproducible example.

Comment: (A) I don't see how `pryr::object_size` (or equivalent) will help for an object that did not get allocated due to insufficient memory. So question still stands. (B) Adding a reproducible example to the question won't hurt if it is possible. If it is a CRAN library you are using, then providing a short code example that crashes similarly could help. (C) could you try stepping through the code using `browser()`? Then you can check the system state just before the error, and see what the code is doing at the point it crashes. That might give you a clue how much memory is being sought.

Comment: Actually his question in post is more about a request that failed to be executed. The question title didn't include all information which is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

A simple search found these possible routes:

1. If you are using linux, [try to change `swap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136264/unable-to-install-packages-system-call-failed-cannot-allocate-memory-instal).
2. If you are using RStudio, [try R console](http://inferenceandinduction.blogspot.com/2014/09/rstudio-installpackages-failing-cause.html)
3. If it's possible, [try with different system configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182054/cant-install-modules-cannot-allocate-memory-error). I think experimenting with different Amazon AWS instance will not cost you too much.
4. try suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485514/can-you-make-r-print-more-detailed-error-messages). Especially `options(error=recover)` or `debugonce`

As others suggested, without a reproducible example it's difficult to get accurate answer to your problem.