# R equivalent to MATLAB's "stop if error"

Tags: debugging, r

I'm attempting to debug an R program, and I'm sorely missing the `stop if error` capability of matlab. I've gone through the [R-debug-tools.pdf](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/docs/R-debug-tools.pdf)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170803163042/http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/docs/R-debug-tools.pdf)) documentation, but it didn't list anything like this. Is there any way to instruct R that, when any error at all is encountered - even one I didn't anticipate and plan for with a custom `trace` function - it should stop execution and throw me into [`browser()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/browser.html) mode?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe you want `options(error=recover)`

Answer (score 5):

R has the wonderful `stopifnot()` which is pretty close to what C has in `assert()`:

> Description:
>
> If any of the expressions in ‘...’ are not ‘all’ ‘TRUE’, ‘stop’ is
>      called, producing an error message indicating the *first* of the
>      elements of ‘...’ which were not true.

That is from `help(stopifnot)` which also has examples, as usual.

Comment: This doesn't put me in `browser()` mode, though.