# Forcing a package's function to use user-provided function

Tags: debugging, r

I'm running into a problem with the `MNP` package which I've traced to an unfortunate call to `deparse` (whose maximum width is limited to 500 characters).

**Background (easily skippable if you're bored)**

Because `mnp` uses a somewhat idiosyncratic syntax to allow for varying choice sets (you include `cbind(choiceA,choiceB,...)` in the formula definition), the left hand side of my formula call is 1700 characters or so when `model.matrix.default` calls `deparse` on it.  Since `deparse` supports a maximum `width.cutoff` of 500 characters, the `sapply(attr(t, "variables"), deparse, width.cutoff = 500)[-1L]` line in `model.matrix.default` has as its first element:

```
[1] "cbind(plan1, plan2, plan3, plan4, plan5, plan6, plan7, plan8, plan9, plan10, plan11, plan12, plan13, plan14, plan15, plan16, plan17, plan18, plan19, plan20, plan21, plan22, plan23, plan24, plan25, plan26, plan27, plan28, plan29, plan30, plan31, plan32, plan33, plan34, plan35, plan36, plan37, plan38, plan39, plan40, plan41, plan42, plan43, plan44, plan45, plan46, plan47, plan48, plan49, plan50, plan51, plan52, plan53, plan54, plan55, plan56, plan57, plan58, plan59, plan60, plan61, plan62, plan63, "       
[2] "    plan64, plan65, plan66, plan67, plan68, plan69, plan70, plan71, plan72, plan73, plan74, plan75, plan76, plan77, plan78, plan79, plan80, plan81, plan82, plan83, plan84, plan85, plan86, plan87, plan88, plan89, plan90, plan91, plan92, plan93, plan94, plan95, plan96, plan97, plan98, plan99, plan100, plan101, plan102, plan103, plan104, plan105, plan106, plan107, plan108, plan109, plan110, plan111, plan112, plan113, plan114, plan115, plan116, plan117, plan118, plan119, plan120, plan121, plan122, plan123, "
[3] "    plan124, plan125, plan126, plan127, plan128, plan129, plan130, plan131, plan132, plan133, plan134, plan135, plan136, plan137, plan138, plan139, plan140, plan141, plan142, plan143, plan144, plan145, plan146, plan147, plan148, plan149, plan150, plan151, plan152, plan153, plan154, plan155, plan156, plan157, plan158, plan159, plan160, plan161, plan162, plan163, plan164, plan165, plan166, plan167, plan168, plan169, plan170, plan171, plan172, plan173, plan174, plan175, plan176, plan177, plan178, plan179, "
[4] "    plan180, plan181, plan182, plan183, plan184, plan185, plan186, plan187, plan188, plan189, plan190, plan191, plan192, plan193, plan194, plan195, plan196, plan197, plan198, plan199, plan200, plan201, plan202, plan203, plan204, plan205, plan206, plan207, plan208, plan209, plan210, plan211, plan212, plan213, plan214, plan215, plan216, plan217, plan218, plan219, plan220, plan221, plan222, plan223, plan224, plan225, plan226, plan227, plan228, plan229, plan230, plan231, plan232, plan233, plan234, plan235, "
[5] "    plan236, plan237, plan238, plan239, plan240, plan241, plan242, plan243, plan244, plan245, plan246, plan247, plan248, plan249, plan250, plan251, plan252, plan253, plan254, plan255, plan256, plan257, plan258, plan259, plan260, plan261, plan262, plan263, plan264, plan265, plan266, plan267, plan268, plan269, plan270, plan271, plan272, plan273, plan274, plan275, plan276, plan277, plan278, plan279, plan280, plan281, plan282, plan283, plan284, plan285, plan286, plan287, plan288, plan289, plan290, plan291, "
[6] "    plan292, plan293, plan294, plan295, plan296, plan297, plan298, plan299, plan300, plan301, plan302, plan303, plan304, plan305, plan306, plan307, plan308, plan309, plan310, plan311, plan312, plan313)"
```

When `model.matrix.default` tests this against the variables in the data.frame, it returns an error.

**The problem**

To get around this, I've written a new `deparse` function:

```
deparse <- function (expr, width.cutoff = 60L, backtick = mode(expr) %in% 
  c("call", "expression", "(", "function"), control = c("keepInteger", 
                                                        "showAttributes", "keepNA"), nlines = -1L)  {
    ret <- .Internal(deparse(expr, width.cutoff, backtick, .deparseOpts(control), nlines))
    paste0(ret,collapse="")
  }
```

However, when I run `mnp` again and step through, it returns the same error for the same reason (`base::deparse` is being run, not my `deparse`).

This is somewhat surprising to me, as what I expect is more typified by this example, where the user-defined function temporarily over-writes the base function:

```
> print <- function() {
+   cat("user-defined print ran\n")
+ }
> print()
user-defined print ran
```

I realize the right way to solve this problem is to rewrite `model.matrix.default`, but as a tool for debugging I'm curious how to force it to use my `deparse` and why the anticipated (by me) behavior is not happening here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions `fixInNamespace` and `assignInNamespace` are provided to allow editing of existing functions. You could try ... but I will *not* since mucking with `deparse` looks too dangerous:

```
 assignInNamespace("deparse", 
                  function (expr, width.cutoff = 60L, backtick = mode(expr) %in% 
               c("call", "expression", "(", "function"), control = c("keepInteger", 
               "showAttributes", "keepNA"), nlines = -1L)  {
    ret <- .Internal(deparse(expr, width.cutoff, backtick, .deparseOpts(control), nlines))
    paste0(ret,collapse="")
                         }   , "base")
```

There is an indication on the help page that the use of such functions has restrictions and I would not be surprised that such core function might have additional layers of protection. Since it works via side-effect, you should not need to assign the result.

Comment: Another caution is given in `?fixInNamespace`: "They [the documented functions] should not be used in production code."

Comment: I got the idea from @gsk3's efforts that this was for "experimental" purposes.

Comment: Thanks, and warnings duly noted.  I'll likely change the function that calls `deparse` rather than `deparse` itself.

Comment: It remains possible that the 500 character limit is put in place because of the design of `.Internal(deparse(.))`

Comment: @Dwin Oh, I suspect that it is.  That's why my code takes the output of `.Internal(deparse(.))` and fixes it after the fact.

Suspicions about further protections were correct.  I can neither fix `deparse` nor `model.matrix.default` which calls it.

Answer (score 3):

This is how packages with namespaces search for functions, as described in [Section 1.6, Package Namespaces](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces) of [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html)

> Namespaces are sealed once they are loaded. Sealing means that imports
>   and exports cannot be changed and that internal variable bindings
>   cannot be changed. Sealing allows a simpler implementation strategy
>   for the namespace mechanism. Sealing also allows code analysis and
>   compilation tools to accurately identify the definition corresponding
>   to a global variable reference in a function body.
>
> The namespace controls the search strategy for variables used by
>   functions in the package. If not found locally, R searches the package
>   namespace first, then the imports, then the base namespace and then
>   the normal search path.

Comment: I figured something like that was going on, so you've pinpointed the problem.  Now how to override? :-)

Comment: @gsk3: You're likely to break something by overriding `deparse`, so I would suggest you find the exact location of `deparse` call you want to change, insert your function right before that call, and restore the original `deparse` immediately after.  You might be able to use `fixInNamespace` to change the function that contains the `deparse` call you want to change.