# Error in <my code> : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, r-faq

I was finally able to work out the code for [my scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11295618/1468366). It seemed to be working fine and then all of a sudden when I ran it again, I got the following error message:

```
Error in url[i] = paste("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/", gsub(" ", "_",  : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I am not sure why as I changed nothing in my code.

Please advise.

```
library(XML)
library(plyr)

names <- c("George Clooney", "Kevin Costner", "George Bush", "Amar Shanghavi")

for(i in 1:length(names)) {
    url[i] = paste('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/', gsub(" ","_", names[i]) , sep="")

    # some parsing code
}
```

Comment: Also it occurs, as in my case, when you just mistakenly type `[]` instead of `()`!

Answer (score 149):

In general this error message means that you have tried to use indexing on a function.  You can reproduce this error message with, for example

```
mean[1]
## Error in mean[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
mean[[1]]
## Error in mean[[1]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
mean$a
## Error in mean$a : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

The closure mentioned in the error message is (loosely) the function and the environment that stores the variables when the function is called.

---

In this specific case, as Joshua mentioned, you are trying to access the [`url`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/connections) function as a variable.  If you define a variable named `url`, then the error goes away.

As a matter of good practise, you should usually avoid naming variables after base-R functions.  (Calling variables [`data`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/topics/data) is a common source of this error.)

---

There are several related errors for trying to subset operators or keywords.

```
`+`[1]
## Error in `+`[1] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable
`if`[1]
## Error in `if`[1] : object of type 'special' is not subsettable
```

---

If you're running into this problem in `shiny`, the most likely cause is that you're trying to work with a `reactive` expression without calling it as a function using parentheses.

```
library(shiny)
reactive_df <- reactive({
    data.frame(col1 = c(1,2,3),
               col2 = c(4,5,6))
})
```

While we often work with reactive expressions in shiny as if they were data frames, they are actually **functions** that return data frames (or other objects).

```
isolate({
    print(reactive_df())
    print(reactive_df()$col1)
})
  col1 col2
1    1    4
2    2    5
3    3    6
[1] 1 2 3
```

But if we try to subset it without parentheses, then we're actually trying to index a function, and we get an error:

```
isolate(
    reactive_df$col1
)
Error in reactive_df$col1 : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Answer (score 39):

You don't define the vector, `url`, before trying to subset it.  `url` is also a function in the base package, so `url[i]` is attempting to subset that function... which doesn't make sense.

You probably defined `url` in your prior R session, but forgot to copy that code to your script.

Answer (score 1):

In case of this similar error 
**Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
  [No stack trace available]**

Just add corresponding package name using :: 
e.g.

instead of tags(....)

write 
shiny::tags(....)

Answer (score 1):

It could mean an undefined variable.

Comment: Undefined dataset for me. Noob error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue was trying to remove a ui element inside an event reactive:

```
myReactives <- eventReactive(input$execute, {
    ... # Some other long running function here
    removeUI(selector = "#placeholder2")
})
```

I was getting this error, but not on the removeUI element line, it was in the next observer after for some reason. Taking the removeUI method out of the eventReactive and placing it somewhere else removed this error for me.

Answer (score -7):

I think you meant to do `url[i] <- paste(...`

instead of `url[i] = paste(...`. If so replace `=` with `<-`.