# read.csv() and colClasses

Tags: r, read.csv

I am trying to use `read.csv()` command, but I do not understand `colClasses` part to run coding. Does anyone explain what it is, and also give me example of simple coding for `read.csv()`?

Also, if I run my coding for `read.csv()`, I get an error

```
> object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

What type of error is this? Last time I run my code, it worked, but now I get this. I am not sure what change I should make here. This is my code:

```
Precipfiles[1:24] <- list.files(pattern=".csv")
> DF <- NULL
> for (f in Precipfiles[1:24]) {
    data[1:24]<-read.csv(f,header=T,sep="\t",na.string="",colClasses="character")
    DF[1:24]<-rbind(DF,data[1:24])
}
```

Basically, I load all data and put them together, but I have not able to use `merge()` command since I am having troubles I listed above.

I think I should not use `colClasses="character"` because data I am using are all numeric in 200 by 200 matrix. There are 24 data files that I have to put them together.

If you have any suggestions and advise to improve this coding please let me know.
Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: Try remove all `[1:24]` indices

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308367/object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable

Comment: It would be interesting to collect on SO questions that are related to using common function names as variables.  `data`, `df` etc.

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it changes the complete meaning. If you have a new (followup) question, search for an answer, then if you can't find one, post as a separate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really don't need the `[1:24]` in every assignment, this is what is causing your problems. You are assign to a subset of a indexed vector of some description.

The error message when are trying to assign to `data[1:24]`, without `data` being assigned previously (in your previous usage (which you mentioned worked), `data` was probably a `list` or `data.frame` you had created.). As such `data` is a function (for loading data associated with packages, see `?data`) and the error you saw is saying that (a function includes  a closure)

I would suggest something like

```
Precipfiles <- list.files(pattern=".csv")
DFlist <- lapply(Precipfiles, read.table, sep = '\t', 
                  na.string = '', header = TRUE)
bigDF <- do.call(rbind, DFlist)

# or, much faster using data.table 
library(data.table)
bigDF <- rbindlist(DFlist)
```

Comment: Never thought of using `rbindlist` on data.frames.  +1!

Comment: mnel, I tried your code, and it much faster, somewhat. Thank you for your help and advice. I thought without [1:24], files becomes one big file and I cannot call one particular number from one particular data file.

Comment: Ricardo Saporta, Why shouldn't I use rbindlist on data.frames?