# How to categorise time values in R

Tags: r

How can I categorise time values to month buckets in R? 

Now

```
time                     
2014-01-31 20:46 +0000   
2014-01-31 10:46 +0000   
2014-02-21 20:16 +0000   
2014-02-11 12:36 +0000
```

my goal

```
time                     month
2014-01-31 20:46 +0000   Jan
2014-01-31 10:46 +0000   Jan
2014-02-21 20:16 +0000   Feb
2014-02-11 12:36 +0000   Feb
```

Comment: `months(as.POSIXct(time))`. Google seem to be on strike today.

Comment: I've pasted my solution in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
time <- c("2014-01-31 20:46 +0000",   
          "2014-01-31 10:46 +0000",   
          "2014-02-21 20:16 +0000",   
          "2014-02-11 12:36 +0000")

library(lubridate)
# first convert it to a proper date-time format and put it in a dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(as.POSIXct(time))
#then simply calculate month
df$month <- month(time, label= TRUE)
```

Which gives:

```
      as.POSIXct(time)  month
1 2014-01-31 20:46:00   Jan
2 2014-01-31 10:46:00   Jan
3 2014-02-21 20:16:00   Feb
4 2014-02-11 12:36:00   Feb
```

Comment: Your example works. I have an issue with my column. When I use your code example and type `typeof(time)` that's what I get back `[1] "character"`. When I try it with my data set I get this message `[1] "closure"`. Is it because I read a CSV file?

Comment: @cosmin Probably. Look at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057202/read-csv-and-colclasses?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

```
data <- read.csv("~/data.csv", 
                header=TRUE, 
                dec=".", 
                sep=",", 
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

```
time <- data$time
time <- as.Date(time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
time
```

```
data$year <- as.factor(format(time, format ="%Y"))
data$month <- as.factor(format(time, format ="%m"))
data$day <- as.factor(format(time, format ="%d"))
```