# Replace Matrix Values with Vectors, One Column at a Time

Tags: r, vector, matrix, subset

Using R, I want to create 10 vectors (say 10x1) and concatenate their results into a matrix (say 10x10) one at a time.

I figured that it might be most computationally-efficient to initialize an empty matrix first and then replace its values, column by column, with the vectors of interest.

This is what I tried.

```
# Initialize empty matrix
empty.m = matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 10)

#Create vectors and attempt to insert them into matrix
for (i in 1:10) {
    empty.m[, i] = sample(10)
}
```

My attempt to insert the output of *sample* into the matrix *empty.m* does not work, yielding the following error:

```
Error in matrix[, 1] = vec : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Do you have any suggestions for what I can do to accomplish what I want, avoiding this error?

Comment: The provided code ran fine for me. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308367/object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable) for an explanation of the error you encountered.

Comment: You called it, @Nick! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much easier way to create the matrix is `replicate`:

```
replicate(10, sample(10))
```

The first `10` represents the number of columns.

Comment: Thanks, Sven! I was looking for something like that function, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Sven, do you know how to do this with different sampling values for each column? I have a data frame that has different values in each of its columns and I want to sample from the respective column for each column of the matrix?

Comment: @user2932774 You can use `sapply(dat, sample)`, where `dat` is the name of your data frame.