# lme - Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, nlme

I am trying to run a linear mixed-effects model (package nlme) but I am repeatdly getting the Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.

```
> apoeht <- read.csv("apoeht.csv")  
> library(nlme)  
> model.a <- lme(Timmrec ~ age, data = apoeht, random = ~ age | pathid, 
+                na.exclude)  
Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're passing `na.exclude` as the fourth argument which is `correlation`.  Instead, use named args there:  `na.action=na.exclude`

Comment: This problem has been already discussed in this forum [here("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308367/object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable")]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a function `na.exclude()` to the `correlation` argument of `lme()`. In effect your call is:

```
model.a <- lme(Timmrec ~ age, data = apoeht, random = ~ age | pathid, 
               correlation = na.exclude)
```

The code that handles the `correlation` argument makes certain assumptions, but it is certainly not expecting to be passed an irrelevant function.

You probably want to use the `na.action` argument, but you must name it if you don't supply the other arguments. You want

```
model.a <- lme(Timmrec ~ age, data = apoeht, random = ~ age | pathid, 
               na.action = na.exclude)
```