# Error in data$Dateid : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I am getting the following error : on the running the below mentioned command 
range(data$Dateid)
Error in data$Dateid : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.... 
when i pull data from the csv file . the code does not show this error . however when i am getting the same data from the an odbc connection i am getting the above mentioned error. Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: I saw some examples about the same issue. What i think is range might not be applicable here. Currently my dateid is in 'int' format. I tried changing it to date format but it creates another issue in my code. So wanted to know if there is a fix on my posted issue.

Comment: this thread may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308367/error-in-my-code-object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable

Comment: Can you post your code? This would make it easier to solve.

Comment: It seems like the a variable named `data` doesn't exist and it's trying to subset the base function named data. (tip: don't name your variable the same name as base/package functions).