# Error in <my code> : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable (2)

Tags: r, mlogit

I know this question has been raised before ([Error in <my code> : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308367/error-in-my-code-object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable)). But I could not get my head around it.

Here is the packages I use and how I prepare my data

```
library(mlogit)

data(CollegeDistance, package="AER")
Data <- CollegeDistance 
Data$Dist[Data$distance<0.4] <- 1
Data$Dist[Data$distance<1 & Data$distance>=0.4] <- 2
Data$Dist[Data$distance<2.5 & Data$distance>=1] <- 3
Data$Dist[Data$distance>=2.5] <- 4
```

Now when I define a `mlogit` object and use it for prediction I get that error.

```
Formula <- paste('Dist ~', paste('1|',paste(c("urban", "unemp", "tuition"), collapse = " + "),'|1')) 
Model <- mlogit(as.formula(Formula), Data, shape='wide', choice='Dist')

Predict <- predict(Model, newdata=mlogit.data(Data, shape='wide', choice='Dist'), returnData=FALSE)
```

The interesting part is that if I replace `Formula` with `formula`then it works!

**UPDATE**

I encounter that problem while using `mlogit` in a function. I really appreciate it if you can show me a way out of it.

```
modelmaker <- function(variables){
  Formula <- paste('Dist ~', paste('1|',paste(variables, collapse = " + "),'|1'))
  MODEL <- mlogit(as.formula(Formula), Data, shape='wide', choice='Dist')  
  return(MODEL)
}

Model <- modelmaker(c("urban", "unemp", "tuition"))
Predict <- predict(Model, newdata=mlogit.data(Data, shape='wide', choice='Dist'), returnData=FALSE)
```

This time is does not solve even by avoiding using `formula` or `Formula`. If you change it to `XXX` the error will be

```
object 'XXX' not found
```

Comment: related: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2015-March/070887.html and following thread ...

Comment: I bet it's getting mad because `Formula()` is a function in the `Formula` package required by `mlogit`...

Comment: this could have been avoided by not calling your formula either `Formula` or `formula` or your dog `dog`, `fortunes::fortune(77)`

Comment: @alexforrence, your hypothesis seems to be correct.  Replacing `Formula` with `Formula1` above makes it work.  It would take too much digging through the guts for me to figure out precisely what's going on though ...

Comment: @rawr, fair enough, but I wouldn't have known easily that I needed to avoid `Formula` as well as `formula` ...

Comment: @BenBolker sure. I am still wondering why `mlogit:::predict.mlogit` finds `Formula::Formula` before `Formula` in `as.environment(1)`, maybe that is in your thread