# Looping statistic Tests in R

Tags: r, loops, statistics

I would like to apply T test in R within a loop

```
Groups  Length  Size    Diet    place
A   2.4048381   0.7474989   1.6573392   334.3273456
A   2.72500485  0.86392165  1.8610832   452.5593152
A   1.396782867 0.533330367 0.8634525   225.5998728
B   1.3888505   0.46478175  0.92406875  189.9576476
B   1.38594795  0.60068945  0.7852585   298.3744962
B   2.53491245  0.95608005  1.5788324   303.9052525
```

I tried this code with loop, but it is not working:

```
for (i in 2:4){
  t.test(table[,c(i)] ~ table$Groups, conf.level = 0.95)
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? 
Thanks!

Comment: I don't actually get an error even if my data frame is called `table`. But generally, [don't use R's function as variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308367/error-in-my-code-object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable) as @zheyuan-li said. Maybe tell us the error you get from R.

Comment: There is no error message , but also it results in nothing heheheh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code computes 4 t-tests, but the results are lost, because you don't do anything with them. Try the following:

```
info <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Groups  Length  Size    Diet    place
               A   2.4048381   0.7474989   1.6573392   334.3273456
               A   2.72500485  0.86392165  1.8610832   452.5593152
               A   1.396782867 0.533330367 0.8634525   225.5998728
               B   1.3888505   0.46478175  0.92406875  189.9576476
               B   1.38594795  0.60068945  0.7852585   298.3744962
               B   2.53491245  0.95608005  1.5788324   303.9052525")

results <- list()
for (i in 2:4){
    results[[i]] <- t.test(info[,i] ~ info$Groups, conf.level = 0.95)
}

print(results)
```

When interacting with the REPL/console, typing the `t.test` function will compute results and return them. The console will print everything that is returned. In scripts that you `source`, the `t.test` function will return results but they wil not be printed. This is why I put them into a list and printed the list later on.

Btw, I stored your information as `info` not as `table`. R will deal great with variable names that are also function names, but every now and then you will hava a hard time to read error messages, so avoid naming variables `table` or `matrix` or `c` or `df`.

Comment: Perfect explanation @Bernhard! It worked very well and as it has few commands I can add more collumns and data :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `apply` functions you could also do:

```
res<- cbind(
do.call(rbind,apply(info[,-1],2,function(cv)t.test(cv ~ info$Groups, conf.level = 0.95)
                    [c("statistic","parameter","p.value")]))
,
t(apply(info[,-1],2,function(cv)unlist(t.test(cv ~ info$Groups, conf.level = 0.95)
                    [c("conf.int","estimate")])))
)
res


> res
       statistic parameter p.value   conf.int1  conf.int2 estimate.mean in group A estimate.mean in group B
Length 0.7327329 3.991849  0.5044236 -1.13263   1.943907  2.175542                 1.769904                
Size   0.2339013 3.467515  0.8282072 -0.47739   0.5595231 0.714917                 0.6738504               
Diet   0.9336103 3.823748  0.4056203 -0.7396173 1.468761  1.460625                 1.096053                
place  0.9748978 3.162223  0.398155  -159.4359  306.2686  337.4955                 264.0791
```