# How to select a directory and output the selected directory in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Please is there any simple way how to allow the user of R Shiny application (locally, not on server) to select a directory from a computer and then output the path? I cannot find an easy way such as `fileInput` for selecting files.
I want the user to be able to search the whole PC for folders and then select the folder, and the path to this folder will be displayed in the Shiny app, such as
`C:\users\Jane\folder`. In the answer below, I am able to search only the current working directory for folders, not the whole PC and the path to the folder is not displayed in the Shiny app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could consider the `shinyFiles` package.

On server side you use
`shinyDirChoose(input, id = 'folder', ...)` and then can access the chosen folder via `input$folder`.

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
shinyApp(
  shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    shinyDirButton('folder', 'Select a folder', 'Please select a folder', FALSE)
  )),

  shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    shinyDirChoose(input, 'folder', roots=c(wd='.'), filetypes=c('', 'txt'))

    observe({
      print(input$folder)
    })
  })
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that I can search the whole PC after I click "Select a folder" button? Now, I cannot search the whole PC for folders, but only my working directory.

Comment: your OS is windows? Would "C:" directory be sufficient? `shinyDirChoose(input, 'folder', roots = c(wd = 'C:'), filetypes=c('', 'txt'))` ?

Comment: Yes, my OS is Windows. `roots = c(wd = 'C:')` is better, so it is not possible to select any directory from anywhere, you have to have this `roots` specified and select a directory from `roots`? And also, how do I output in the app the chosen directory? With `input$folder` I get the list and all its elements, but I want just to print out the directory like `C:\folder`

Comment: 1) To my knowledge you have to specify the drive, but i am no expert there. You could have a workaround and use a selectInput to specify which drive to use. 2) Look in your console. There the directory is printed, see: `observe({
      print(input$folder)
    })`

Answer (score 5):

Some folks are asking about how to choose your directory differently. You can do this by changing the specification for `roots` as I do below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyDirButton('folder', 'Select a folder', 'Please select a folder', FALSE)
)
server <- function(input, output){
  volumes = getVolumes() # this makes the directory at the base of your computer.
  observe({
    shinyDirChoose(input, 'folder', roots=volumes, filetypes=c('', 'txt'))
    print(input$folder)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add up one side note for this question:

I was trying to apply this function to my codes, but I kept getting [object of type ‘closure’ is not subsettable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40623749/20736900) error. I tried multiple ways and finally figured it out using [GitHub discussion page](https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles/issues/138#issuecomment-626243105).

I figured the issue is coming from `getVolumes` function. Instead of using `getVolumes()`, `getVolumes()()` helped me resolve the error. I still don't totally understand why, but hopefully it helps other to solve this mysterious error.