# How can i solve this error : "Error in: object of type 'closure' is not a subset" in shiny APP using datatables

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt, shinyapps

I am making an app with shiny, and I need a datatable that reacts to an input, but when I render the datatable I get the following error

> Error in: object of type 'closure' is not a subset

This is the function in server.R

```
  output$elites <- renderUI({
    req(input$iterationsElites)
    allElites <- iraceResults$allElites[[input$iterationsElites]]
    for(i in allElites)
    {
      bestConfiguration <- getConfigurationById(iraceResults, ids=i)
      print(bestConfiguration)
    }
    DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(
        bestConfiguration
      )
    })
  })
```

ui.R

```
      fluidRow(
          box(title = "Elite Configurations",
              status = "primary",
              numericInput("iterationsElites","Select Iteration",value = 1,min = 1,max = iraceResults$state$nbIterations),
              uiOutput("elites"),
              width = 15
          )
        ),
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

getConfigurationByID:

```
  .ID. algorithm localsearch alpha beta  rho ants q0 rasrank elitistants nnls  dlb .PARENT.
7    7        as           0  4.96 0.81 0.27   32 NA      NA          NA   NA <NA>       NA
   .ID. algorithm localsearch alpha beta  rho ants q0 rasrank elitistants nnls dlb .PARENT.
52   52        as           1  0.35 6.72 0.11   92 NA      NA          NA    8   0       NA
   .ID. algorithm localsearch alpha beta  rho ants q0 rasrank elitistants nnls dlb .PARENT.
73   73        as           3  0.61 2.29 0.66   34 NA      NA          NA   22   1       NA
   .ID. algorithm localsearch alpha beta  rho ants q0 rasrank elitistants nnls dlb .PARENT.
67   67      mmas           3  2.73 7.98 0.97   34 NA      NA          NA   41   0       NA
   .ID. algorithm localsearch alpha beta  rho ants q0 rasrank elitistants nnls dlb .PARENT.
58   58       eas           2  0.32 2.97 0.72   80 NA      NA          58    6   1       NA
```

The variable allElites contains the ID for get the configuration through the function getConfigurationByID

```
[1]  7 52 73 67 58
```

Thanks for answering

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [What is “object of type ‘closure’ is not subsettable” error in Shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623749/what-is-object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable-error-in-shiny)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Where do functions like `getConfigurationById` come from? I don't think you want to nest a `renderDataTable` inside a `renderUI`

Comment: This looks suspicious: `allElites <- iraceResults$allElites[[input$iterationsElites]]`. Yes, you should give us your data.

Comment: allElites is a dataframe from IRACE library. How can i render the datatable if i have teh data in "bestConfiguration" variable? Im stucked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"An object of type closure" means a function. The error message means you are trying to subset (ie, use $ or brackets with) a function, which obviously makes no sense.

So go through your code looking for objects that seem like subsettable data objects but actually have the name of a function and you'll find your problem.

Often this error is a result of misspelling the name of the data object. Note that if you define a data object using the name of an existing function, R will find the data object first. But if try to subset a data object you named "Sum" and refer to it as "sum" (which is the name of a built-in function), you'll get this error.