# Row names of values in R / DESeq

Tags: r

I am trying to find the name of the genes significantly different genes that have been generated after running DESeq, I run the following code:

```
results(dds1and2, contrast = c("Time","A0","G0"))
length(which(resA0vsG0$padj < 0.01))

rownames(results[which(resA0vsG0$padj < 0.01), ])
```

However I receive the following error:

> Error in results[which(resA0vsG0$padj < 0.01), ] : 
>     object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Is there another way to find the names of what genes are different? The DESeq generates a set of values rather than a dataset I cant view the data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in <my code> : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308367/error-in-my-code-object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable)

Comment: You get this error because you're trying to subset on a function which is not allowed, it looks like you make a call to `results` in your first line then try to subset results with square brackets and get the error.