# nls2 with nested functions

Tags: r, nls, nested-function

I am trying to find parameters using the `nls2` package. As the formula I am trying to optimize parameters for is quite complex, I try to use functions that I call within the formula I optimize with the `nls2` command:

```
library(nls2)

set.seed(20160227)
x <- seq(0,50,1)
y <- ((runif(1,10,20)*x)/(runif(1,0,10)+x))+rnorm(51,0,1)

a <- function(){
d+1
}

f1 <- function(){
y <- a()*x/(b+x)
}

st <- data.frame(d = c(-100,100),
                 b = c(-100,100))

nls2(f1,start = st, algorithm = "brute-force")
```

Currently, this throws the error

> Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

I found this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308367/error-in-my-code-object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), however when I assign values to `b` and `d` this works:

```
 a()*x/(b+x)
```

I assume the problem is that I try to find `b` and `d` using functions that already have them inside?

What is the best way to do this? Is it even possible or do I need to define the entire complex formula within `nls2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `f1` nor `a` here have any parameters, so it's not really surprising that it's having some difficulty understanding how you want to optimize `f1`.

`nls2::nls2` (like `stats::nls`) expects a `formula` as the first parameter. That formula can be built from any function you want, and does not have to be written down entirely in the call. You could do the following:

```
a <- function(d){
  d+1
}

f1 <- function(b,d,x){
  y <- a(d)*x/(b+x)
}
```

And then fit the model like this:

```
nls2(y~f1(b,d,x), start = st, algorithm = "brute-force")
```

Because no `start` value is provided for `x`, and because its actual value can be found in the environment, it won't optimize over `x`, just `b` and `d`.

Comment: Perfect, you eased a lot of pain and of course the answer now seems crystal clear when I see it in front of me. Thank you so much!