# Creating new column based on values in one column over another

Tags: r

I have some data

```
structure(list(Factor = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Col_A = c(45L, 
23L, 35L, 43L, 42L, 23L, 11L), Col_B = c(85L, 67L, 55L, 40L, 
27L, 85L, 12L), New_Column = c(45L, 67L, 35L, 40L, 27L, 23L, 
12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Pretend that the 4th column is not there. I need to write a script that based on the value in the `Factor` column will take a value from either `Col_A` or `Col_B` and put in `New_Column`. If the value in `Factor` is 0 it should take the value in `Col_A` so the value in `New_Column` in the first row is 45.

Comment: `df %>% mutate(New_Column = ifelse(Factor==0,Col_A,Col_B))`

Comment: @maydin tried something like this on real data and received this error  `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Comment: So ,share the just a few part of your real data. You can use `dput(head(data))`. By the input you gave above, this approach works well.

Comment: I cannot share my data. However, one thing I can add is that there are NA values in this. would that change anything?

Comment: So I suggest, have a look at the error message, try to solve it wrt the anwers. Because your problem is not about the solution of the problem above. You may start from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308367/error-in-my-code-object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable)

Answer (score 0):

A base solution:

```
df$New_Column <- ifelse(df$Factor == 0, df$Col_A, df$Col_B)
```

Comment: I tried something like this on my actual data and received this error 
 ` object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` (before anyone asks, I legally cannot share the real data)

Comment: The problem is that with your fake data, works well. Can't you creare some fake data that makes your error? Maybe a kind of transformation of your real data.

Comment: ok interesting thing here. I subset the data taking only the columns of interest and the code works now. But on the whole dataset it doesn't work. So I can splice back in the correct column, but now I'm just curious why it does not work on the same exact data but with other columns included. I'll add there's no difference in structure

Comment: If you've subset the dataset by columns, try to add one by one the other columns, to fetch the one that create the problem (trying to find a solution of a blackbox).

Comment: that sounds like a good call. This dataset's structure is so messed up so that could be it. I'll come back to this once ive written everything up

Answer (score 0):

We can use `row/column` indexing to get the value

```
df1$New_Column <- df1[2:3][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1$Factor + 1)]
```

Comment: A typical uncommon solution by akrun. Welcome back champion :)