# error occur says object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r

i'm new to R and below is my code but i cant knit the file to html because it says object of type 'closure' is not subsettable, how should I change my code?

```
mean(data$salary)
[1] 865.8644
```

how to change my code to let it works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in <my code> : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11308796/5221626)

Comment: We need a reproducible example if possible. You are probably failing to define `data` *within your Rmarkdown file*; knitting uses a new, clean environment so it won't see variables that you have only defined in your global workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Check you code upstream, you're probably reassigning `data` to something else.

When you knit a document, R executes everything sequentially, it might be the case that you're doing something like this.

```r
data <- actual_dataframe
...
couple lines below
...
data <- 1
...
# then you hit your error
mean(data$salary)
```

Comment: Hi, I didn't add anything upstream, i have a table called data which include salary information, so i use mean(data$salary) to find the mean, but occur with this error

Comment: I think this might be backwards. OP is probably *failing* to assign a value to `data`, so the `data` function from base R is being found instead. The code you've posted throws a different error ("$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors")