# List shp files fails with large number of files

Tags: r, loading, shapefile

I have been using the following to important .shp files into R fine for ages:

```
require(maptools)
require(rgeos)

shp <- lapply(list.files(pattern="*.shp"), readShapePoly)
```

If I am loading a handful of files it works fine. However, I am trying to load in ~1000 files and I just get the (common) error message:

```
Error in getinfo.shape(filen) : Error opening SHP file
```

I have been searching online but have not been able to find a solution. The working directory is set correctly, the accompanying .dbf .shx and .prj files are present for each shapefile. Also,

```
list.files(getwd(),pattern="shp")
```

does return every file. So I'm a bit confused, am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change your `lapply` to a loop or use the [`options(error=recover)` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442518/general-suggestions-for-debugging-r) to figure out which file is giving you trouble.

R shapefile functions tend to be picky about file extensions, unfortunately.  Make sure that all the capitalization on all the different files which collectively make up a shapefile are consistent.

If you think that it's a particular file, you can use `try` or `tryCatch` to catch the error.

Comment: options(error=recover) is really useful, unfortunately it just lists the first two file sets (1 name with the 4 extensions) as problematic, which work if tested on just their own

Comment: Try it with one file if it works. Try specifying the full path or try specifying the name of the shape file *without the extension* .shp. I remember there were some changes in rgdal and some discussion on the mailing list.

Comment: And: which version of R, maptools, all the other packages maptools depends on moght be useful ( sessinInfo() )
Works for me:
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)
[1] rgeos_0.2-12    maptools_0.8-22 lattice_0.20-13 sp_1.0-5       
[5] foreign_0.8-52 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.2

Comment: If it's not working for any, maybe it's a path issue.  Try `,full.names = TRUE` in `list.files()` .  Also try `lapply(list.files(pattern="*.shp")[[1]], readShapePoly)` and see if you can get the same error.  If so, compare `list.files(pattern="*.shp")[[1]]` to the character string you know works.

Comment: Or stop using `readShapePoly` and use `readOGR` from the `rgdal` package.

Comment: including '[[1]]' works fine and pulls out the first file. 'readOGR' gives me a new error of missing layer. Could this be a memory issue if i'm loading lots of large files, i've seen that people have had issues  handling lots of large shapefiles elsewhere. also, the packages are all up to date

Comment: Tried converting to loop:  `k <- length(list)

    x <- vector(mode="list",length=k)

    for (i in 1:k) {

    x[[i]] <- readShapePoly("*.shp")

    }` but no luck

Comment: `x[[i]] <- readShapePoly("*.shp")` isn't right in your loop.  Need a specific filename for each iteration.

Comment: I have sorted it....a file was corrupted. Annoying. I am ticking the response above because I have noted all of the comments below for future reference

Comment: @NickCrouch Retroactively added a suggestion for `try` so that it solves your problem :-)