# Warning Message Line Number R

Tags: r

I've got a big for loop that loops for hundreds of times and at its end it produces this warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In min(j, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Is there any way I could ask R which line the warning message was generated at?

---

OP's comment below: 
"I don't directly have min as a line. Its probably nested in other functions else I wouldn't have asked the question as I knew it was a problem coming from min."

Comment: It looks like you are giving the function min() a bad input.

Comment: All data to `min` are `NA` is what it says. Try: `min(rep(NA, 10), na.rm=T)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try setting:

```r
options(warn = 2)
```

... to treat warnings as errors. Then, when your code stops at the first warning, use [`traceback()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/traceback.html) to see the stack trace.

This will only help you with the first warning though.

To go back to the default behaviour, use:

```r
options(warn = 0)
```

Comment: Not really a solution... more like a poor workaround. I don't know why R ignores the line numbers. Very hard for debugging.

Comment: This did not work for me. The `traceback()` returns "no traceback available". But the following equivalent of `options(error=recover)` for warnings was useful:  `options(warning.expression=quote(recover()))`

Comment: Instead of this work around can anyone specify dierct way to locate line number of warning?

Comment: @Harsh your proposed solution causes my warning is disappear entirely

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic `for` loop howto, not really `R` dependent

Right before your `min` line put

```
 print(paste("j is", j, "\n"))  # or instead of j, use i, or whichever index you are using     
 min(j, na.rm = TRUE)
```

then you will have a good idea of where the error is.

---

As for a more `R` relevant solution, if j is coming from a data.frame, matrix, list, etc,
you want to find which chunk (iteration portion) has nothing but `NA`s.

For that you can use something like

```
  apply(myDF, 1, function(x) all(is.na(x)))
```

Comment: I don't directly have min as a line. Its probably nested in other functions else I wouldn't have asked the question as I knew it was a problem coming from min.

Comment: Mentioning that in your original question would have been helpful.  If that is the case then your best bet is to use `traceback()` as @NPE suggests

Comment: @Tomas, it was an answer to the question as it was originally posted. Look at the edit history. I added to the question the information that was left as a comment to this answer.