# What arguments were passed to the functions in the traceback?

Tags: r, debugging

In R, if execution stops because of an error, I can evaluate `traceback()` to see which function the error occurred in, which function was that function called from, etc.  It'll give something like this:

```
8: ar.yw.default(x, aic = aic, order.max = order.max, na.action = na.action, 
       series = series, ...)
7: ar.yw(x, aic = aic, order.max = order.max, na.action = na.action, 
       series = series, ...)
6: ar(x[, i], aic = TRUE)
5: spectrum0.ar(x)
4: effectiveSize(x)
```

Is there a way to find what arguments were passed to these functions?  In this case, I'd like to know what arguments were passed to `effectiveSize()`, i.e. what is `x`.

The error does not occur in my own code, but in a package function.  Being new to R, I'm a bit lost.

Not knowing how to do this properly, I tried to find the package function's definition and modify it, but where the source file should be I only find an `.rdb` file.  I assume this is something byte-compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest setting `options(error=recover)` and then running the offending code again. This time, when an error is encountered, you'll be thrown into an interactive debugging environment in which you are offered a choice of frames to investigate. It will *look* much like what `traceback()` gives you, except that you can type `7` to enter the evaluation environment of call `7` on the call stack. Typing `ls()` once you've entered a frame will give you the list of its arguments.

An example (based on that in `?traceback`) is probably the best way to show this:

```
foo <- function(x) { print(1); bar(2) }
bar <- function(x) { x + a.variable.which.does.not.exist }

## First with traceback()
foo(2) # gives a strange error
# [1] 1
# Error in bar(2) : object 'a.variable.which.does.not.exist' not found
traceback()
# 2: bar(2) at #1
# 1: foo(2)

## Then with options(error=recover)
options(error=recover)
foo(2) 
# [1] 1
# Error in bar(2) : object 'a.variable.which.does.not.exist' not found
# 
# Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   
# 
# 1: foo(2)
# 2: #1: bar(2)

Selection: 1
# Called from: top level 
Browse[1]> ls()
# [1] "x"
Browse[1]> x
# [1] 2
Browse[1]>    ## Just press return here to go back to the numbered list of envts.
# 
# Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   
# 
# 1: foo(2)
# 2: #1: bar(2)
```

R has many helpful debugging tools, most of which are discussed in the answers [to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442518/general-suggestions-for-debugging-r/5156351#5156351) from a few years back.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `trace()` to tag or label a function as requiring a "detour" to another function, the logical choice being `browser()`.

```
 ?trace
 ?browser

> trace(mean)
> mean(1:4)
trace: mean(1:4)
[1] 2.5
```

So that just displayed the call. This next mini-session shows trace actually detouring into the browser:

```
> trace(mean, browser)
Tracing function "mean" in package "base"
[1] "mean"
> mean(1:4)
Tracing mean(1:4) on entry 
Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
Browse[1]> x      #once in the browser you can see what values are there
[1] 1 2 3 4
Browse[1]> 
[1] 2.5
> untrace(mean)
Untracing function "mean" in package "base"
```

As far as seeing what is in a function, if it is exported, you can simply type its name at the console. If it is not exported then use: `getAnywhere(fn_name)`

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit please or maybe give an example?  This is very dense for a beginner.