# R: matrix of doubles turns into a matrix of strings

Tags: r

I've got a really weird problem with a matrix of doubles turning into a matrix of strings. I cut down my code to the following problem:

```
num.samples <- nrow(expr.matrix)
num.genes <- ncol(expr.matrix)
gene.names <- colnames(expr.matrix)

# Define a function which returns a vector in order to... 
execute.per.gene <- function(target.gene, ...) {
    # Uninteresting code
    x <- expr.matrix[,setdiff(1:num.genes, target.gene)]
    y <- expr.matrix[,target.gene]
    rf <- randomForest(x, y, mtry=10, ntree=100, importance=TRUE)

    # Calculate importance measure
    im <- importance(rf)[,"IncNodePurity"]

    # Divide by number of samples
    im / num.samples
}

# ... execute mclapply!
all.output <- mclapply(1:num.genes, execute.per.gene, mc.cores=mc.cores)

# Initialise matrix
weight.matrix <- matrix(0.0, nrow=num.genes, ncol=num.genes)
rownames(weight.matrix) <- gene.names
colnames(weight.matrix) <- gene.names

# And now I merge the results from 'all.output' into the weight.matrix
for (target.gene in 1:num.genes) {
    # Get result
    im <- all.output[[target.gene]]

    # Find which rows to change for this column
    cand.tf.idx <- match(names(im), gene.names)

    # Merge results into output matrix
    weight.matrix[cand.tf.idx, target.gene] <- im
}

# And suddenly, the matrix consists of a bunch of strings!
if (!is.numeric(weight.matrix[[1,1]])) { # dafuq
    cat("\nEncountered strings! :/\n")
    print(weight.matrix)
    # recently added this for debugging purposes:
    print(sapply(all.output, class))
    browser()
}
```

The output is:

```
Encountered strings! :/
      G1  G7  G9  G23 G26 G28 G29 G33 G44 G48 G50 G52 G55 G59 G63 G64 G69 G70
G1    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"
G7    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"
G9    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"
G23   "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"
G26   "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"
...
```

And I have *no* clue why the matrix is turning into a bunch of strings containing zeros. After all, in the `execute.per.gene` method, the last thing I do is divide the vector by an integer and the problem doesn't throw an exception at that point, so therefore `im` must be still a vector of doubles at that point.

Does anybody see where the problem lies? What am I doing wrong?

---

Update, `im` should always look somewhat like the following. If `im` already consisted of strings, I figure `im / num.samples` would fail.

```
    > dput(im)
    structure(c(3.86421872658217, 0.0600404651226161, 0.0729843866848986, 
    0.0556398483535666, 0.0488815568218319, 0.0526059937835038, 0.170688282373908, 
    0.129655447072086, 0.174050696716209, 0.244770969072866, 0.170282014024477, 
    0.100440545265572, 0.0634773436494396, 0.0696835665372604, 0.118303002740336, 
    0.0493612110879677, 0.103414668075989, 0.0149516634700066, 0.0377397612656266, 
    0.0462366818296757, 0.0534595079995701, 0.0418429987271517, 0.0521335103883387, 
    0.0454590053400778, 0.0620792864477719, 0.0528642019860386, 0.0440233200010488, 
    ....
    2.4293680818691, 0.0455845647048088, 0.0480473721971548, 0.0493418345253576, 
    0.0468391879447859, 1.53509517636789, 0.0639471582428624, 0.155340800410008, 
    0.0668494853135931, 0.0436381864919185, 1.09024170028797, 0.0649503734307499, 
    0.0490042073829033, 0.0304435411561372, 0.034892331733943, 0.0759421587532521, 
    0.0666974014679768, 0.913196971375135, 0.0550660353121449, 1.36191204205922, 
    3.63194611493454, 0.177078251458191, 0.17856008667256, 0.0499985787306069, 
    0.0465138307009715, 0.071656156183379, 0.0441178391009568, 0.239933902772204, 
    0.0719828575374175, 0.0654148345872996, 0.920668929212975, 0.0454979263784418, 
    2.92899170564573, 0.0208273505572265, 0.0397416566013167, 0.197310579354446, 
    0.0313568556466712), .Names = c("sample_2", "sample_3", "sample_4", 
    "sample_5", "sample_6", "sample_7", "sample_8", "sample_9", "sample_10", 
    "sample_11", "sample_12", "sample_13", "sample_14", "sample_15", 
    "sample_16", "sample_17", "sample_18", "sample_19", "sample_20", 
    "sample_21", "sample_22", "sample_23", "sample_24", "sample_25", 
    "sample_26", "sample_27", "sample_28", "sample_29", "sample_30", 
    "sample_31", "sample_32", "sample_33", "sample_34", "sample_35", 
    "sample_36", "sample_37", "sample_38", "sample_39", "sample_40", 
    "sample_41", "sample_42", "sample_43", "sample_44", "sample_45", 
    "sample_46", "sample_47", "sample_48", "sample_49", "sample_50", 
    "sample_51", "sample_52", "sample_53", "sample_54", "sample_55", 
    "sample_56", "sample_57", "sample_58", "sample_59", "sample_60", 
    "sample_61", "sample_62", "sample_63", "sample_64", "sample_65", 
    "sample_66", "sample_67", "sample_68", "sample_69", "sample_70", 
    "sample_71", "sample_72", "sample_73", "sample_74", "sample_75", 
    ....
    "sample_801", "sample_802", "sample_803", "sample_804", "sample_805"
    ))
```

And more information on `gene.names`, `num.samples` and `num.genes`:

```
> dput(num.samples)
1643L
> dput(num.genes)
805L
> dput(gene.names)
c("sample_1", "sample_2", "sample_3", "sample_4", "sample_5", 
"sample_6", "sample_7", "sample_8", "sample_9", "sample_10", 
"sample_11", "sample_12", "sample_13", "sample_14", "sample_15", 
"sample_16", "sample_17", "sample_18", "sample_19", "sample_20", 
"sample_21", "sample_22", "sample_23", "sample_24", "sample_25", 
"sample_26", "sample_27", "sample_28", "sample_29", "sample_30", 
"sample_31", "sample_32", "sample_33", "sample_34", "sample_35", 
"sample_36", "sample_37", "sample_38", "sample_39", "sample_40", 
...
"sample_741", "sample_742", "sample_743", "sample_744", "sample_745", 
"sample_746", "sample_747", "sample_748", "sample_749", "sample_750", 
"sample_751", "sample_752", "sample_753", "sample_754", "sample_755", 
"sample_756", "sample_757", "sample_758", "sample_759", "sample_760", 
"sample_761", "sample_762", "sample_763", "sample_764", "sample_765", 
"sample_766", "sample_767", "sample_768", "sample_769", "sample_770", 
"sample_771", "sample_772", "sample_773", "sample_774", "sample_775", 
"sample_776", "sample_777", "sample_778", "sample_779", "sample_780", 
"sample_781", "sample_782", "sample_783", "sample_784", "sample_785", 
"sample_786", "sample_787", "sample_788", "sample_789", "sample_790", 
"sample_791", "sample_792", "sample_793", "sample_794", "sample_795", 
"sample_796", "sample_797", "sample_798", "sample_799", "sample_800", 
"sample_801", "sample_802", "sample_803", "sample_804", "sample_805"
)
```

Comment: As long as we don't know how `all.output` looks like or have an example of one `im` it could be difficult to find out where the error is.

Comment: There are so many simple debugging steps available to you that will be much more informative than we could ever be, with the information provided. Ditch the parallelization, and step through your process on just one gene. Use `debug` or `browser` to carefully examine your objects during the course of execution in `execute.per.gene` and `foo`.

Comment: @Henrik: Sure, I added some more information on the workings of 'im'

Comment: @joran: Thanks, but can I use breakpoints with debug or browser? The problem occurs only once every 30 minutes which makes this problem incredibly frustrating to debug. Without breakpoints I'd be stepping through code for quite a long time.

Comment: when you put `browser()` somewhere, this is a breakpoint. Hit enter to continue or look at the current environment.

Comment: Also, `str(im)` and/or `dput(im)` could be helpful.

Comment: Set `options(error=recover)`. Then, when the error is thrown, you will be popped into a browser, of sorts, from which you can enter any of the frames that were active at the time of the error. At that point, go to a frame from which you can have a look at `im`'s value, and check whether it's a character vector. [Here is an example of what that process looks like.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492761/what-arguments-were-passed-to-the-functions-in-the-traceback/16493150#16493150)

Comment: Alright, I inserted `browser()` in the last if-statement. I'm waiting for the problem to occur. In the meantime, I added the `str(im)` and `dput(im)` outputs in the main post.

Comment: Alternatively, posting `dput(gene.names)` and `dput(num.genes)` could also help.

Comment: Can you please run `sapply(all.output, class)`? Any "character" in there? If so, it will tell you which iteration is the culprit so you can focus on debugging that one in particular.

Comment: @Henrik: Added the dput's for `gene.names`and `num.genes`, as well as their definitions in the code. @flodel: Also added a `sapply(all.output, class)` in the if-statement, waiting for output :)

Comment: Re: waiting - That's why I said you should ditch the parallel stuff and debug this on just a subset. You'll drive yourself bonkers doing debugging on the full process.

Comment: The other problem is, your sample data does **not** produce the problem.

Comment: @joran: You're right; I'm trying to find a smaller problem on which the problem also occurs, for that I need to wait for the problem to occur at least once again.

Comment: I cut down the `ntrees` parameter down to `1`, which decreases the amount of iterations for the random forests algorithm, hopefully this will speed up the process a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, I found the problem :)

Under some very unlikely conditions `expr.matrix` contains some NaN values, something the randomForests algorithm flips out on.

The `browser()` tip was quite useful!