# Relation of xts Time Series and Error in if (ncol(x) == 1) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r

I am quite newbie in R but I am trying to manage to get through.
I am working with time series dataset that I have set up via this code:

```
myts <- as.xts(df[,-1], order.by = as.POSIXct(df$DATE_3, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

=> my data series are hourly data that goes from 2006 to 2017

I have done simple lm regressions without any troubles. Then I started to test the statistical assumptions, I had no problems testing stationary of series and heteroscedasticity, however, on serial correlation, I tried to use following code:

```
library(car)
dwt(didreg6) 'didreg6 is the name of one of my regressions
```

but I received this error.

```
Error in if (ncol(x) == 1) { : argument is of length zero
```

I have tried to traceback() whether I mange to find any clue how to solve the error. I have received:

```
 1: dwt(didreg6)
 2: durbinWatsonTest(...)
 3: durbinWatsonTest.lm(...)
 4: matrix(sample(residuals, n * reps, replace = TRUE), n, reps)
 5: as.vector(data)
 6: as.vector(x, mode)
 7: as.vector.zoo(x, mode)
 8: as.vector(as.matrix(x), mode = mode)
 9: as.matrix(x)
10: as.matrix.xts(x)
```

As I was not able to identify where the problem is, I have tried Ljung-Box because I though, maybe it would work.

```
Res<-residuals(didreg6)
Box.test(Res, lag = 1, type = "Ljung-Box")
```

However, I received another error, that I would guess relates to time series.

```
Error in if (frequency > 1 && abs(frequency - round(frequency)) < ts.eps) frequency 
<-   round(frequency) : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

After, because I found out that my data series error is heteroscedastic, I wanted to use HAC errors instead of standard. I typed in this code:

```
library(estimatr)
didreg6_robust <- lm_robust(lnEL ~ sum of my explanatory variables, data = myts,      
se_type = "stata")
summary(didreg6_robust)
```

But the same error showed up again:

```
Error in if (ncol(x) == 1) { : argument is of length zero
```

Eventually, I tried to use different coding for HAC errors:

```
didreg6 <- lm(lnEL ~ sum of my explanatory variables, data = myts)       
summary(didreg6)
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)
coeftest(didreg6, df = Inf, vcov = vcovHC(didreg6, type = "HC0"))
```

However still received an Error in if (ncol(x) == 1) { : argument is of length zero
Follows the traceback():

```
 1: coeftest(didreg7_coef, df = Inf, vcov = vcovHC(didreg7_coef, type = "HC0"))
 2: coeftest.default(didreg7_coef, df = Inf, vcov = vcovHC(didreg7_coef, type = "HC0"))
 3: vcovHC(didreg7_coef, type = "HC0")
 4: vcovHC.default(didreg7_coef, type = "HC0")
 5: meatHC(x, type = type, omega = omega)
 6: estfun(x, ...)
 7: estfun.lm(x, ...)
 8: as.vector(res)
 9: as.vector(x, mode)
 10: as.vector.zoo(x, mode)
 11: as.vector(as.matrix(x), mode = mode)
 12: as.matrix(x)
 13: as.matrix.xts(x)
```

I have read many articles about this error, however, neither of them deals with the issue, that the error is probably related time series. I have no missing data in whole dataset. (["Error in 1:ncol(x) : argument of length 0" when using Amelia in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543949/error-in-1ncolx-argument-of-length-0-when-using-amelia-in-r)) But I think, the error is in the first column, hence the column where I store the date and time.

Here is a preview of my dataset, maybe it will help in solving the issue:
[Data preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq729.png)

Moreover I am getting really desperate, because I have no clue what is the reason for this error that still popups and how to deal with it.

Where is the mistake I made?

Comment: I have an idea. Maybe, it is caused by the fact that I am transforming my Dataset in xts, but x remains in front of the date. What can I do about it? How can I remove x? Or how differently can I set up the hourly time frame not using xts? Or is there any different reason?

Comment: Could you `dput()` your data - or a sample that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 1):

Converting it back from xts to numerical array solves it. Yes, the issue seems to be with the xts object. You can solve it as follows:

`fit_dw <- lm( as.numeric(xts1) ~ as.numeric(xts2) + as.numeric(xts3) )`
`durbinWatsonTest(fit_dw )`

where xts1,xts2,xts3 are xts objects with one time series inside them.