# traceback() returns useless information for error happened during source()

Tags: r, debugging

I am surprised by how hard it is to find where the error happened exactly in R when I am sourcing a file. For example:

```
> source('Data-Generation.R')
... # some output here
Error in as.matrix(X) %*% coefs[ix_X] : non-conformable arguments
```

At least in this case, I can find where it is by searching for it because I have `as.matrix(X) %*% coefs[ix_X]` only once in my code. Anyway, if I try to pinpoint where it happened with `traceback()`:

```
> traceback()
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval(ei, envir)
2: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
1: source("Data-Generation.R")
```

which is useless information.

Am I doing something wrong?

Edited: I am looking for a solution which will produce a message that Python would yield:

```
$ python .\test.py

1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: Check out various solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442518/general-suggestions-for-debugging-r

Answer (score 2):

Set `echo = TRUE`:

```
source(textConnection("i <- 1
                      y*x
                      3+4"), echo=TRUE)
#> i <- 1
#
#>                       y*x
#Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found
```

`verbose = TRUE` might also be useful:

```
source(textConnection("i <- 1
                      y*x
                      3+4"), verbose=TRUE)
#'envir' chosen:<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
#--> parsed 3 expressions; now eval(.)ing them:
#
#>>>> eval(expression_nr. 1 )
#        =================
#
#> i <- 1
#curr.fun: symbol <-
# .. after ‘expression(i <- 1)’
#
#>>>> eval(expression_nr. 2 )
#        =================
#
#>                       y*x
#Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While it does work in finding out where the error happened, it is really not ideal solution with several hundreds of lines of code. I was looking for something like Python's error message.

Comment: Well, why do you have scripts lying around that produce errors? If you  structured your code with functions, `traceback` results would be a bit more useful.

Comment: +1 for using functions: `source(textConnection("f <- function() y_; f()")); traceback()`.

Comment: @Roland Well, I don't know how to respond to your question (you have never had a code snippet that produces error outside of a function?), but let me just say I was experimenting with the data :) With a function, `traceback` does produce useful information. Thanks. This is pretty inconvenient behavior, IMO.

Comment: @joon Well, I do (usually because I've updated some package and that broke my code). I usually open the script in RStudio and work from there. I almost never source scripts, so that's not an issue for me. But I somewhat agree with you, R's debugging facilities could be better.

Comment: @joon Here's one way to respond to Roland's question: because we do not have control over what other people have written in the past. These "if things were different, there would not be a problem" comments are of no practical problem-solving use.