# Erratic behaviour of traceback() with Rstudio: different output every time

Tags: r, rstudio, traceback

I use RStudio; I have script1 importing script2 with `source` ; a function in script2 causes an error. The first time it happens, Rstudio tells me that script 1 at row x caused an error in script2 at row y. If I rerun it, it only tells me about the error in script2. Why? This can make debugging much more painful than it needs to be.

More in detail:

I have a `myfun.R` file which contains this function (of course this is just a toy example):

```
sum_2_nums <- function(x,y) {
  out <- x + y
  return(out)
}
```

I then import the function into another file using `source`:

```
source("myfun.R")
mysum <- sum_2_nums(3,"hello")
```

RStudio is set to `debug -> on error -> error inspector`. When I run the code above, I see:

[image]

which tells me that an error in myfun.R, row 12 was caused by try_traceback.R, row 13. Great.

However,  if I run the script again, I get:

[image]

i.e. the error no longer gets traced back to `try_traceback.R`. I need to type `traceback()` in the console to see that. Why? The different behaviour the second time really puzzles me. This makes debug needlessly more painful than it needs to be! Is there a way to avoid it?

Note **this questions is *not* a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151552/traceback-returns-useless-information-for-error-happened-during-source)**: they may look similar but the answer given there of using `echo=TRUE` or `verbose=TRUE` does *not* address my point about tracing the error to the first .R file.

I saw the same question [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-does-the-traceback-feature-work-sometimes/12372), but it remains unanswered.

### Edit

To clarify, in answer to some comments:

- like I said, if I click on Debug -> on Error -> I see that "error inspector" is ticked.
- if I type `options(error=function()traceback(1))` in the console, nothing happens on screen, but "error inspector" becomes deselected
- I do not have anything else in my code. It is a toy example with only the lines I have shown, and nothing else. I do not know what else I can clarify - any guidance would be most appreciated.
- I am very new to R. I use Python for data analysis but am curious to understand about R. I had heard that debugging was much more cumbersome in R and wanted to try for myself. Let's say I am not going to invest a lot of my time learning R if even only tracing back such a banal error is so problematic, so I'd like to understand if I am doing something wrong, or debugging and tracing back are always like this in R
- when I say "run" I mean I click the "source" button in RStudio (the button next to "run"
- sessionInfo() shows:

```
sessionInfo() R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11) Platform:
x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.3 tools_3.5.3    yaml_2.2.0
```

### **Edit #2** (in reply to duckmayr's answer)

Let's maybe take a step back. In Python I am used to always seeing a rather detailed traceback of what called what when there is an error. E.g. when I see something like this, I find it very helpful:

[image]

The first screenshot I posted of R studio is quite similar, and similarly helpful. **So my expected output would be to get the full traceback every single time the error occurs.**

Why? Because that's most helpful to me; what would possibly be the advantages of NOT showing it every time? I don't get it.

Are you instead saying that it is by design that the full traceback is not listed every time? If so:

- Why? Is there a fundamental reason I am missing? Is there any scenario where this makes more sense than what I am used to with Python?
- Is this documented anywhere? I couldn't find it.
- Is there a way to get the full traceback every single time? A setting to change? Would exiting and reopening RStudio do?

Yes, I understand I can always type traceback(), but Python's behaviour of showing the full traceback every single time is much more convenient - I genuinely fail to see what the upside of showing the traceback only the first time would be.

Comment: Can't reproduce this.
What else do you have in there? it says myfun.R#12, so that's 12 lines of code...

Comment: when you say "when I run the code above", are you running it by doing source("try_traceback.R") or actually running them in rstudio?

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous My sense is that you need to more fully articulate your example and environment. For example, what are your traceback settings in RStudio? `options(error=function()traceback(1))` and your `sessionInfo()` details? Looking at the detail of your explanation my sense is that you are getting different results because your environment has changed. In executing the code, you are creating new variables that change the behaviour of other code. That is my immediate supposition anyway. Hopefully, that will help point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Technophobe01 , I have edited the original question to address your points

Comment: What is in `try_traceback.R`? Is it the two lines `source("myfun.R");
mysum <- sum_2_nums(3,"hello")`?

Comment: @duckmayr Yes, that's right. I have put together a stupid minimalist toy example with the sole purpose of trying to understand how debugging and traceback work in R

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous I'll look into this tomorrow. My sense is that you want a) A way to always show traceback, and B) an explanation of why you see this behaviour. Correct? Further to this, you may find Advanced R Debugging chapter useful - it is available online. https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html You may also find https://github.com/coatless/errorist useful.

Comment: @Technophobe01 Thank you. Yes, you are exactly right on A) and B) ! I will also check out your links

Answer (score 1):

I find it somewhat difficult to get precisely what behavior you are wanting RStudio to give you, but it may help you if I post some information about what is expected.

- The full traceback is not listed every time: In my experience, RStudio only automatically prints the full traceback the first time a function is executed in its current form. If you change your code, then the very next call should also automatically print the full traceback. This behavior may or may not be automatically configurable. **However, more importantly**:
- The R functions `traceback()` and `debug()` are always available to you, regardless of RStudio's settings! So, the first time I `source` your script, I see:

[image]

Then if I `source` your script with nothing else changed, I get:

```
> source('~/try_traceback.R')
Error in x + y : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

But, this is no problem; I can just run:

```
> traceback()
5: sum_2_nums(3, "hello") at try_traceback.R#2
4: eval(ei, envir)
3: eval(ei, envir)
2: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
1: source("~/try_traceback.R")
```

I could also use `debug(sum_2_nums)` to re-run the function with debug.

Additionally, if I change `sum_2_nums()` in `myfun.R` to the following:

```
sum_2_nums <- function(x,y) {
    cat("")
    out <- x + y
    return(out)
}
```

I again see

[image]

when I try to `source` your script.

So you may disagree, but I do not find debugging to be difficult in R, just remember the functions `traceback()` and `debug()` and you'll be alright.

Comment: I edited the original question to reply. Is it one of those "not a bug but a feature" thing that only shows you the traceback the first time?