# Can you access a variable that is within a function if it's not a global by doing something like functionname.someVar?

Tags: r

I'm working through an R tutorial. Currently I'm writing a script that, in it's current format I know is incorrect.

I'd like to "see" the variables I've created within the function within the console so that I can learn about them. I know that writing global variables is discouraged.

So if I have a function `foo` and within foo is a variable called `someVar` is there a way, once I've loaded in the script with the function to, for example go like this:

`str(foo.someVar)` or `str(foo(somevar))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but if you want to walk through a function, you can use `debugonce(functioname)` before calling a function to break into a debugger when a function is called and you can then view variables internal to the function inside the debugger.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442518/general-suggestions-for-debugging-r) for more debugging tools in R.