# mirt simdata Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : too few positive probabilities

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the `mirt` package in `R` to simulate responses from a multidimensional item response model, via the `simdata()` function.

In the [jstat article introducing the package](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v48/i06/paper) simulated data are used to illustrate the `confmirt()` function, and the code used to produce the simulated data is presented in Appendix B, as

```
library(mirt)
a <- matrix(c(1.5, NA, 0.5, NA, 1, NA, 1, 0.5, NA, 1.5, NA, 0.5,
              NA, 1, NA, 1), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

d <- matrix(c(-1, NA, NA, -1.5, NA, NA, 1.5, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA,
               3, 2, -0.5, 2.5, 1, -1, 2, 0, NA, 1, NA, NA), 
               ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

sigma <- diag(2)
sigma[1, 2] <- sigma[2, 1] <- 0.4

simdata2 <- simdata(a, d, 2000, sigma)
```

This doesn't work, because the `simdata()` function has since been updated, and now requires the item type be specified. However, when I try to amend the code by specifying the item type as dichotomous, `simdata2 <- simdata(a, d, 2000, "dich", sigma)`, the function still will not run for me, and I get the error noted in the title `Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob): too few positive probabilities`.

I tried to dig into this to try to understand what was going on, but was unsuccessful. If I could understand what was causing the error it would help me to avoid it when I try to create my own simulated dataset (in my initial trials, I did receive this same error). The questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584894/error-in-sample-intlengthx-size-replace-prob-too-few-positive-probabili) was similar, but I was still unable to diagnose exactly what was causing the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For any interested, the answer to this question is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mirt-package/-jBgwcMd1hI). Essentially, I didn't look at the `d` matrix closely enough to recognize that items 5:7 are polytomous, and thus the `itemtype` argument needs to be a vector, i.e., `type <- c(rep('dich', 4), rep('graded', 3), 'dich')`. Then `simdata2 <- simdata(a, d, 2000, sigma, itemtype = type)`.