# Recurrent error: could not find function "function (object, ...) \nobject"

Tags: r, logistic-regression, data-modeling, propensity-score-matching

#adding packages and features

```
install.packages('MatchIt')
library(MatchIt)
ldata <- MatchIt::lalonde
ldata$hispan <- ifelse(ldata$race=='hispan',1,0)
ldata$white <- ifelse(ldata$race='white',1,0)
```

#model to find propensity scores

```
propscores <- fitted.values(glm(treat~age+educ+white+hispan+married+nodegree+re74+re75,
                                family=binomial, data=ldata))
```

#Returns error:

```
Error in `function (object, ...) \nobject`(list(treat = c(1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  could not find function "function (object, ...) \nobject"
```

Code worked on my professor's code, but not on mine. I'm not sure why? I've tried library(glmnet) in case it's to do with the glm() function not being recognised.

Comment: Same error was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27725144/6912817)

Comment: I could not replicate. There was a syntax error in `ifelse(ldata$race='white',1,0)` which should be `ifelse(ldata$race=='white',1,0)` with double equals. Perhaps you have an object in your global environment that's causing an issue by shadowing something important. Taking a look at `conflicts(detail=TRUE)` much show something useful. Have you also tried restarting R and running everything again?

Answer (score 0):

Have had same problem, fixed after restarting R