# How to work out "Error in tbl_vars(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default" in Shiny?

Tags: r, database, ggplot2, shiny

I really need some useful help.

I've wrote code, but it doesn't work. However, nearly same example is working perfectly.

Here is what I got:

```
      Warning: Error in tbl_vars: argument "y" is missing, with no default
      Stack trace (innermost first):
        45: tbl_vars
        44: as.vector
        43: base::intersect
        42: intersect.default
        41: intersect
        40: common_by
        39: inner_join.tbl_sql
        38: inner_join
         1: shiny::runApp
        Error in tbl_vars(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

I'm new to R and especially Shiny.
Please, help.

Here is the code and [dataset](https://groups.google.com/group/shiny-discuss/attach/5878fc4ce80a9/corruption.db?part=0.1&authuser=0&view=1) + files are attached.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
library(datasets)

actionLink <- function(inputId, ...) {
tags$a(href='javascript:void',
     id=inputId,
     class='action-button',
     ...)
     }

     shinyUI(fluidPage(
     titlePanel("Corruption: Evidence from round the World" ),
     fluidRow(
     column(4,
     wellPanel(

textInput("country", "Country's Name"),


     selectInput("country", label = h5("Select the Country"), 
                 choices = list("All" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2,
                                "Choice 3" = 3, "All"), selected = 1),
     selectInput("country", label = h5("Select the Kind of Country's Association"), 
                 choices = list("EU" = 1, "BRICS" = 2,
                                "None" = 3), selected = 3),

       sliderInput("cpi", "Corruption Perception Index", 0, 100, step = 1, value = 27), # в скобках значения, которые горят для привлечения внимания к панели и объясняют, как ей пользоваться


       sliderInput("ief", "Index of Economic Freedom", 0, 100, step = 0.1, value = 51.9),                   


       sliderInput("hdi", "Human Development Index", 0, 1, step = 0.01, value = 0.80),


       sliderInput("gini", "GINI Index", 0, 100, step = 0.1, value = 41.6),                   

textInput("crate", label = h5("Credit Rating (S&P)"), value = "Enter rating..."))
  )
),
   fluidRow(
   column(4,  
   wellPanel(

selectInput("xvar", "X-axis variable", axis_vars, selected = "gdp"),
selectInput("yvar", "Y-axis variable", axis_vars, selected = "hdi")
  ),

    mainPanel(
    ggvisOutput("plot")

    )))
    )
    )
```

server.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(ggvis)
    library(dplyr)
    if (FALSE) library(RSQLite)


    db <- src_sqlite("corruption.db")
    corruption <- tbl(db, "corruption")

    all_c <- inner_join(corruption)


    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    corruption <- reactive({
    gdp <- input$gdp
    gni <- input$gni
    finv <- input$finv

c <- all_c %>%
  filter(
    CPI >= cpi,
    IndexOfEconomicFreedom >= icf,
    HDI >= hdi,
    GINI >= gini
  ) %>%
arrange(CPI)

  })

  vis <- reactive({

xvar_name <- names(axis_vars)[axis_vars == input$xvar]
yvar_name <- names(axis_vars)[axis_vars == input$yvar]

xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$xvar))
yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$yvar))

corruption %>%
  ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar) %>%
  layer_points(size := 50, size.hover := 200,
               fillOpacity := 0.2, fillOpacity.hover := 0.5) %>%
  add_axis("x", title = xvar_name) %>%
  add_axis("y", title = yvar_name) %>%
  set_options(width = 500, height = 500)

    })

     vis %>% bind_shiny("plot")

    })
```

global.R

```
      axis_vars <- c(
      "Corruption Perception Index" = "cpi",
      "Index Of Economic Freedom" = "icf",
      "HDI" = "hdi",
      "GINI" = "gini",
      "Foreign Investments" = "finv",
      "GDP per capita" = "gdp"
       )
```

Great THANKS in advance!!!!

Comment: Just reading through the code, I'm pretty sure it's this line: `all_c <- inner_join(corruption)` since `tbl_vars` is a dplyr function and you're not including y value.  For what it's worth, the Server.R script is running in the R session when the server is running, so you can use your [favorite debug method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442518/general-suggestions-for-debugging-in-r) within that script.

Comment: UPD: after launching `traceback()` I got: `5: Sys.sleep(0.001)
4: withCallingHandlers(expr, error = function(e) {
       if (is.null(attr(e, "stack.trace", exact = TRUE))) {
           calls <- sys.calls()
           attr(e, "stack.trace") <- calls
           stop(e)
       }
   })
3: captureStackTraces(while (!.globals$stopped) {
       serviceApp()
       Sys.sleep(0.001)
   })
2: ..stacktraceoff..(captureStackTraces(while (!.globals$stopped) {
       serviceApp()
       Sys.sleep(0.001)
   }))
1: shiny::runApp("Desktop/shinyapp1")`

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem and this question led me to the solution. Here

```
all_c <- inner_join(corruption)
```

should be something like

```
all_c <- some_other_table %>% inner_join(corruption)
```

So the error message is from dplyr and not from shiny.