# How do I track down where a R package function fails?

Tags: debugging, r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [General suggestions for debugging R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442518/general-suggestions-for-debugging-r)

I've encountered an error when calling a function from an R package. Briefly,

```
> library(treemap)
> ...
> tmPlot(X,index=c("r1","r2","r3","r4"),vSize="size")
Error in if (maxI == 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

[This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034748/treeemaps-with-more-than-two-levels-in-r) question gives more details.

I examined  the source code of `tmPlot` by typing `tmPlot` at the R prompt, but the line that fails doesn't appear in the function. Which means, I assume, that it's failing in some function called by `tmPlot`.

What's the best way to track this down? For example, can I generate a stack trace somehow? Is there an interactive debugger that will allow me to step through and see where the error happens?

Comment: Duplicate of [General suggestions for debugging R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442518/general-suggestions-for-debugging-r) and [Debugging tools for the R language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169480/debugging-tools-for-the-r-language) and [What is your favorite R debugging trick?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882734/what-is-your-favorite-r-debugging-trick)

Comment: You mean "package" not library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

traceback will print the call stack.

```
traceback()
```

Also, have a look at the on-line help for the debug function.  Although I have seen better interactive debuggers, there is some basic functionality provided by debug(), debugonce() and undebug()

```
?base::debug
```