# Could Emacs Speaks Statistics loop through a R for loop like a real debugger?

Tags: debugging, r, emacs, ess

I am a happy user of ESS for coding and debugging R code. I have found a elusive bug recently deeply inside several for loops and ifs structures.

Is there any way of having ESS selectively travel the if/else structures or loop for all the values in a for loop?.

Does R or ESS have debugger mode where you can skip else clauses, loop the values and step into, step through, return etc?

**[UPDATE]**

Thanks @jubba for the link to the other SO question about [debugging tools for R-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169480/debugging-tools-for-the-r-language). At the end this was my real question. This other thread give the links for the kind of things that I wanted to know about the way of doing debugging in the current R.

- [R-debug-tools.pdf](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/%7Erpeng/docs/R-debug-tools.pdf)
- [debuggingR](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/murdoch/software/debuggingR/)
- and the one for debugging with ESS, [ess-tracebug](http://code.google.com/p/ess-tracebug/)

Comment: I have not put this question as a duplicate because I don't know how to do it, I hope to remember to google for it later ;-)

Comment: New version of [ess-tracebug](http://code.google.com/p/ess-tracebug/) is available. It includes plenty of new cool features like watch window, debug/undebug on the fly of functions and methods. It also includes an interactive recover mode which makes it easy to navigate during the recover or dumped frames.

Comment: here is the today's announcement: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/ess-help/2011-March/006718.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There has been a more general question about debugging in R on Stackoverflow :

[Debugging tools for the R language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169480/debugging-tools-for-the-r-language)

One answer by Davor Cubranic points to `ess-tracebug` which is, according to its website, *"An emacs package for interactive debugging and error tracing in ESS"*. I've never used it myself, but it may be useful to you :

http://code.google.com/p/ess-tracebug/

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169480/debugging-tools-for-the-r-language). It give the links for the kind of things that I wanted to know about the way of doing debugging in the current R.
[R-debug-tools.pdf](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/%7Erpeng/docs/R-debug-tools.pdf) and 
[debuggingR](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/murdoch/software/debuggingR/)
and the one you provided